# find the correlations using loop or lapply in R

Tags: r

I want to find the correlations between variables.
I have data set like this

```
     ID A B C
[1,]  1 1 1 0
[2,]  2 0 0 1
[3,]  3 1 0 0
[4,]  4 1 0 1
```

And I want to use cor() function and get this:

```
 cor_AB cor_AC cor_BC
[1,]    0.5  0.012   0.46
```

Comment: `cor(DF[,-1])`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should get you what you want:

```
set.seed(9025)
dat = data.frame(id=1:4, a=rnorm(4), b=rnorm(4), c=rnorm(4))
dat
#   id          a          b          c
# 1  1  1.0339032  1.1523611  0.6029744
# 2  2  1.5605713 -0.4773037  0.7484699
# 3  3  1.5165112  1.8949990 -1.5356641
# 4  4 -0.5837422 -1.1165541  0.2414511

x = cor(dat[, -1])
x
#            a          b          c
# a  1.0000000  0.6377170 -0.2289408
# b  0.6377170  1.0000000 -0.6468663
# c -0.2289408 -0.6468663  1.0000000

cors = x[lower.tri(x)]
cors
# [1]  0.6377170 -0.2289408 -0.6468663
```